# Angular reload Providers Value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I created a web application with Angular. Actual I have a problem with my providers.

```
{
    provide: MY_PROVIDER_DATA,
    useValue: localStorage.getItem('lang') ? localStorage.getItem('lang') : 'de'
},
```

As you can see I am setting the value of MY_PROVIDER_DATA from my localStorage if it exists. If not, It will use the default value of 'de'. If I am updating the value of the localStorage-entry, my MY_PROVIDER_DATA doesn't detect any changes and it still uses the first value until I am reloading the page. After a page reload it takes the new value. Is there any possibilty to change the value without a page reload?

Regards

Comment: You need to use `useFactory` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done with such a simple provider. The provider won't raise an event for you to catch when it's value is getting updated. But If you still insist on working with such a provider, you'll have to sample it's value every `x` milliseconds with an `rxjs` func. Because this is not what I recommend you to do I don't add an example of that...

My solution for you is to change your provider to a service which will handle the latest `lang` value. Inject it to your components and you'll get changes to `lang` variable.

Here is a [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shared-service-so-59635000) with this example code below:

**shared.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {
  langChanged = new Subject<string>();
  lang = localStorage.getItem('lang') || 'de';

  constructor() {
    this.langChanged.subscribe(lang => {
      this.lang = lang;
      localStorage.setItem('lang', lang);
    });
  }
}
```

**some.component.ts**:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy  {
  sub: Subscription;
  lang: string;

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {
    this.lang = sharedService.lang;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.sharedService.langChanged.subscribe(lang => {
      this.lang = lang;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }

  onChangeLang(): void {
    this.sharedService.langChanged.next('en');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But My components gets already the latest language value. My problem is, that i have installed ng-recaptcha (google recaptcha). And to change the Language of the re-captcha i need to set the language throught the provider. But the provider takes the value only on page refresh.